# Nuxt webpack aliases in WebStorm

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, webstorm, nuxt.js

Nuxt (2.10)/Typescript (3.6)

In WebStorm (2019.2.3) we have to create a fake webpack.config.js in order to make path aliases work in IDE:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    // for WebStorm
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname),
      assets: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets')
    }
  }
}
```

Then in a .vue file:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.test {
  background: url('~assets/svg/ios.png');
}
</style>
```

Would work in webpack, but WebStorm complains about it:

[image]

Is there a way to make webpack aliases to work inside style or even in .scss file itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont work in 2019.2.3. It will work only in latest WebStorm EAP.

Comment: You mean fake webpack? FYI 2019.3 EAP doesn't work either, i have both version installed.

Comment: Yes, it do work in 2019.3 . Check if  fake config is set in configuration options

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37978 is fixed in 2019.3, so it should work in [2019.3 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/nextversion). If it doesn't work for you, please submit a ticket to youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: @Aldarund, does it work for you inside a `<template>` and `<img src="~/assets/png/test.png />`

Comment: @AlexanderKim no, its different issue that isnt fixed even in latest EAP https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FWEB-38331
right now it will only work for css section

Comment: @lena, is fix to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38331 in progress?